# How to map array to element of other corespodning array?

Tags: php, arrays

I Have an array A

```
$A = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A0;B0;C0;E0;;626.00;
        [1] => A1;B1;C1;E1;;6212.00;
        [2] => A2;B2;C3;E2;;226.00;
        [3] => A3;B3;C3;E3;;632.00;
    )


)

$B = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => REP00
        [1] => 
        [2] => REP02
        [3] => 
    )
)
```

I am going to write the

```
function map_array_element($A,$B){
    $C = array();
    foreach($A as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            $empty_case = str_replace(';;', ';&nbsp;', $v);
                $row = explode(';', $replace);
              /*the idea to got the array of 
            $row=array(
                    0=>A,
                    1=>B,
                    2=>C,
                    3=>E,
                                4=>   //this element will map to corresponding $B           )
            */
          //TODO


    }
  }
return $C;
}
```

Tthis function will return an new array like this that will

```
   $C = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A0;B0;C0;E0;REP00;626.00;
        [1] => A1;B1;C1;E1;;6212.00;
        [2] => A2;B2;C3;E2;REP02;226.00;
        [3] => A3;B3;C3;E3;;632.00;
    )


)
```

Who know to do this manipulate?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to take care of the right index of array `C`.

```
function map_array_element($A,$B){
        $C = array();
        foreach($A as $key=>$value){
                foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                        $row = explode(';', $v);
                        $row[4] = $B[$key][$k];

                        $C[$key][$k] = implode(';',$row);    
                }
        }
        return $C;
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/MQ6jL)

Comment: @ odaddict, no need to third paramter ($index).

Comment: the element need to be insert always 4

Comment: @python: You can just delete that parameter (see my updated post) or make it a default argument with default value of `4`.